# Method Does Not Override Any Method From Its Superclass: Swift/UITableViewController/MapKit

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a mapView with an autocomplete search bar, and I'm getting a `Method Does Not Override Any Method From Its Superclass` error. Here is my sample of code where this error occurs:

```
extension LocationSearchTable {
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return matchingItems.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    return cell
}
}
```

This is the function that is creating an error:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to clarify some things.

I assume:

- Your `LocationSearchTable` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`.
- You use Xcode 8/Swift 3 or later.
- You do not get errors or warnings on the line:
  `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
  section: Int) -> Int {`

And you should better show where you get that code showing the error, it seems very, very old.

Better find how the methods of `UITableViewDataSource` looks like in the latest Swift, which, you know, `UITableViewController` conforms:

[UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)

> ...
>
> [`func tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath) ->
>   UITableViewCell`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview)
>
> ...

Imported method names are more *swiftified* in recent Swifts, and you should be careful when using old code fragments.

Try changing the method header to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Please do not forget the empty label `_` for the first parameter, and the second parameter label is `cellForRowAt`, not `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and its type is `IndexPath`, not `NSIndexPath`.

And one more, you may get an error if you remove `override`.

Comment: Thank you that worked! However, the matching search results aren't appearing in my search controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a tableView to a view, you should set the tableview's delegate and datasource to a object, and implement method of datasource and delegate if you need.